# Combining two window.onscroll functions

Tags: javascript

I have two `window.onscroll` functions, each one works, however when they are both added only the one listed first will work. How can I combine these two functions?
One function scrolls the header of my table while the other implements a Return to Top function.

```
<script>
const myEventHandlers = {
toggleSticky: function() {
let header = document.getElementById("ipfixedheader");
let sticky = header.offsetTop;

if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
  header.classList.add("sticky");
} else {
  header.classList.remove("sticky");
}
},
toggleButton: function() {
if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
  document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "block";
} else {
  document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "none";
}
},
scrollToTop: function() {
document.body.scrollTop = 0;
document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {
myEventHandlers.toggleSticky();
});
</script>
```

Sticky function works, scroll to top button works, but when clicked does not go to top.

Comment: Use an event listener instead of assigning to window.onscroll. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: I am not the most proficient javascript coder.. I tried to put one of the window.onscroll events in an event listener, but it didn't work, probably because I don't know what I'm doing :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was too long for a comment so here is an example of attaching 2 events to the scroll event of the document. Basically, just call `window.addEventListener("scroll" ...` twice to add your handlers.

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(e){
 console.log('First Event Handler');
});

window.addEventListener("scroll", function(e){
 console.log('Second Event Handler');
});
```

```css
div{
  height: 5em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  asdasd
</div>
<div>
asdasd
</div>
<div>
  asdasd
</div>
<div>
asdasd
</div>
<div>
  asdasd
</div>
<div>
asdasd
</div>
<div>
  asdasd
</div>
<div>
asdasd
</div>
<div>
  asdasd
</div>
<div>
asdasd
</div>
<div>
  asdasd
</div>
<div>
asdasd
</div>
<div>
  asdasd
</div>
<div>
asdasd
</div>
<div>
  asdasd
</div>
<div>
asdasd
</div>
<div>
  asdasd
</div>
<div>
asdasd
</div>
<div>
  asdasd
</div>
<div>
asdasd
</div>
<div>
  asdasd
</div>
<div>
asdasd
</div>
```

**EDIT**
Here is an example based on your updated code in your question. I have put comments in the code to explain it for you.

```js
// Let's declare all the functions you want to execute in your event listners so they are all in 1 place
const myEventHandlers = {
  toggleSticky: function() {
    // find the header and get the offset
    let header = document.getElementById("ipfixedheader");
    let sticky = header.offsetTop;

    if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
      header.classList.add("sticky");
    } else {
      header.classList.remove("sticky");
    }
  },
  toggleButton: function() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
      document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "block";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "none";
    }
  },
  scrollToTop: function() {
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
  }
}

// Now let's add a new event listner for each of the function you want to call
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {
  myEventHandlers.toggleSticky();
});

window.addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {
  myEventHandlers.toggleButton();
});


// As you can quickly see you don't actually need 2 event handlers because you could simply add your call to myEventHandlers.toggleButton inside the first event listener.
// Also you never actually called your scrollToTop function, so you need to add that call where it makes sense.
```

Comment: Changed code in original post to one wrapped in event listener, only the second event works.

Comment: Too quick... while the button shows up in function 2, it does not bring you to the top of the page.

Comment: @user1857409 I think you are misunderstanding how to structure your code and how to use these event listeners. I'll update my answer to clean up your code for you.

Comment: Actually the scrolltotop function is there: // When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
function topFunction() {
    document.body.scrollTop = 0; // For Safari
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0; // For Chrome, Firefox, IE and Opera
}

Comment: CODE comes from here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_scroll_to_top.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sticky_header.asp

Comment: I put what you added into the page, the sticky header functions, the button appears. But the button does not bring you to top, it does nothing...

Comment: @user1857409 Looking at the examples int he links you provided, you would need to make sure you are actually getting your header element, I updated the code to use `let header = document.getElementById("myHeader");` for that then added the button to the header and the relevant CSS from that example. I also had to update the click event on the button to call  `myEventHandlers.scrollToTop()`

Comment: yes my header was changed to ipfixedheader, so that is good for my code, I changed the button to have scrollToTop insted of topFunction, but the button still goes nowhere.

Comment: @user1857409 can you post your full code to jsfiddle and send me the link so I can take a look at what's going on?

Comment: Ok, so in order to make it work in JSFiddle I updated it to use `window.myEventHandlers = { ... ` instead of `const myEventHandlers` and then updated all the references to `myEventHandlers` to be `window.myEventHandlers`. The issue was you were just calling `scrollToTop()` instead of `myEventHandlers.scrollToTop()`  Here is the link to the working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wv9xynof/24/

Comment: Glad I could help.